# Google Analytics API whitelisting DNS proxy

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to ingest data from Google Analytics by calling their API. (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java)

However we are behind a corporate proxy. Now we have a proxy server where I can whitelist the addresses, however I am not sure if I have them all. Does somebody have a full exhaustive list of all the endpoints called?

My list so far is:

- https://accounts.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/
- https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer some time ago: apparently this is not possible.